# Overriding in Java

Tags: java, overriding

Is there a way to override a Java method that the only thing that changes is an ArrayList?

For example:

```
public void quickSortMethod(ArrayList<Integer> comparison, int start, int end)   
{}   

public void quickSortMethod(ArrayList<Double> comparison, int start, int end)   
{}
```

This currently gives me the following error:

```
Method quickSortMethod(ArrayList<Integer>, int, int) has the same erasure quickSortMethod(ArrayList<E>, int, int) as another method in type QuickSort
```

Btw I'm using other objects I created as parameters in the ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<MyObject>...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) after compilation there's no difference between the two.

Comment: Do I have to create two methods (using a different name) that the only thing that changes in both of them is the parameter? Any suggestion?

Comment: You could go that route, yes. What is it you're doing inside this method with that `ArrayList` ?

Comment: If I have ArrayList<MyObject>, MyObject has many variables, one of them is a number(double). I want to sort the ArrayList based on that variable. The problem is: I have MyObject2 and MyObject3, which are different from MyObject but I want to sort them too.

Comment: One idea would be to make all your Objects implement the `Comparable` interface, then make it `ArrayList<Comparable>`. In each of your classes you implement the `compareTo()` method which allows you to have each class sort on the criteria you want.

Answer (score 10):

In this case you could try making the method itself generic and using that type as the ArrayList type...

```
public <T> void quickSortMethod(ArrayList<T> comparison, int start, int end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the answer: You can't do what you're proposing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make that into one function with

```
ArrayList<Object>,int,int
```

and then based on the object type of arraylist employ different analysis

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be using those array lists as parameter objects, you could define your own custom objects which inherit from Arraylist. This way, the compiler will recognize your overload as having distinct signatures.

Of course, this means any client code WILL need to know which sub-type to pass. But that should be a relatively easy problem to address, becaus eif you know you are feeding your parameter object ints, then initialize an integerParamList. Likewise for doubles.

Without knowing a little more about the rest of your code, this may or may not be an appropriate solution, but it may get close? (I wasn't able to test this, so there may be unknown issues . . .)

```
public class mySortingClass {

    public void quickSortMethod(IntegerParamList comparison, int start, int end)    
    {}    

    public void quickSortMethod(DoubleParameterList comparison, int start, int end)    
    {} 

}

public class IntegerParamList extends ArrayList<Integer>
      {}

public class DoubleParameterList extends ArrayList<Integer>
      {}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is a valid example of overriding and here is the also answer of 
  Can we override the static method?
  Answer is NO.**

here is the sample code.

```
  package com.sample.test;
```

class Animal {

```
public static void showMessage() {
    System.out.println("we are in Animal class");
}
```

}

class Dog extends Animal {

```
public void DogShow() {
    System.out.println("we are in Dog show class");
}

public static void showMessage() {
    System.out.println("we are in static overridden method of dog class");
}
```

}

class Cat extends Animal{

```
public static void showMessage(){
    System.out.println("we are in overridden cat class");
}
```

}

public class AnimalTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    animal.showMessage();

    Dog dog = new Dog();
    dog.showMessage();

    Animal animal2 = new Dog();
    animal2.showMessage();

    Animal animal3 = new Cat();
    animal3.showMessage();

}
```

}

**OUTPUT:**

we are in Animal class
we are in static overridden method of dog class
we are in Animal class
we are in Animal class